# Contact form with a popup doesnt work

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, popup

I have a section of my webpage where the products appear from a popup (dialog jquery) in this new windows for each product it has a contact form and the button "Submit" - "Enviar" in spanish doesnt work to send the email using PHP.

Do you know why?

```
       <div class="fruticola dialog"> 
         <div class="fields floatl rel">
                <?php
                if (!isset($_POST['email'])) {
                ?>
                <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
                        <label class="text-field white rel">
                              Teléfono o correo electrónico </br>
                              <input size="35" class="rounded" name="telefono-correo" type="text" style="margin-left:15px; margin-bottom: 10px;" /> </br>
                        </label>

                        <label class="text-field white rel">
                              Mensaje </br>
                              <textarea class="textarea rounded" name="mensaje" rows="6" cols="20"></textarea>
                        </label>
                        </br>
                      <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="boton-enviar"/>
                </form>
               <?php 
                }else{
                  $mensaje="Mensaje del formulario de contacto...";
                  $mensaje.= "\nTeléfono o correo: ". $_POST['telefono-correo'];
                  $mensaje.= "\nMensaje \n".$_POST['mensaje'];
                  $destino= "sample@gmail.com";
                  $remitente = $_POST['email'];
                  $asunto = "Mensaje de interés sobre el producto: ....";
                  mail($destino,$asunto,$mensaje,"FROM: $remitente");
                ?>
                  <p class="center rel text"><strong>Mensaje enviado.</strong></p>
                  <a href="javascript:history.back()">
                    <p class="center rel text" style="font-size:9px; margin-bottom:185px;"><strong>Regresar</strong></p>
                  </a>
                <?php
                }
               ?>

            </div>                    
        </div>
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is vague -- what doesn't work?  What is happening, and what did you expect?

Comment: Does the form appear again when you click on the submit button? Where is `$_POST['email']` set ?

Comment: Ed, when I click on Submitt button theres no event to send the form.

Comment: RMK, when I use this basic form in a simple page works perfectly, but in this popup (.dialog) dont work